# How to iterate through jquery selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to figure out how jquery selectors work when selecting a group of elements. Once i have the all of the elements i am trying to iterate through and check a style value of them to find which one has that and it does not seem to work. Do i have to iterate through them differently? Thank you for any help. I have tried searching and messing with it and this is what i have as of now.

```
function toggle() {
    //get all the content divs
    var $all_divs = $('.content_div');

    //find the content div that is visable
    var $active_index = -1;
    for (i = 0; i < $all_divs.length(); i++) {
        if ($all_divs[i].style.display == "block") {
            $active_index = i;
        }
    }

    $all_divs[$active_index].style.display = "none";
}
```

edit:

Some more info on where i am headed with this.

Basically i have 4 divs, and when i click a button i want the one that is visible to go away, and the next one in the list to appear.

Whole code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<style type="text/css">
.wrapper {
    width:450px;
    height:30px;
    position:relative;
}

.slide_button {
    width:25px;
    height:30px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
}

#left {
    left:0;
}

#right {
    left:425px;
}

.content_div {
    width:400px;
    height:30px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:25px;
}
</style>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
function toggle() {
    var Divs = $('.content_div');
    var i;
    var index = 0;

    Divs.each(function(index) {
        if ($(this).css('display') == 'block')
            i = index;
        index++;
    });

    if(typeof i !== 'undefined'){
        Divs.eq(i).css('display', 'none');
    }
}
</script>


</head>

<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="slide_button" id="left">
        <center><a href='javascript:toggle();'><</a></center>
    </div>
    <div id='div1' class='content_div' style="display:block;">
        this is div 1
    </div>
    <div id='div2' class='content_div' style="display:none;">
        this is div 2
    </div>
    <div id='div3' class='content_div' style="display:none;">
        this is div 3
    </div>
    <div class="slide_button" id='right'>
        <center>></center>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note: your loop does not `break` out once it finds the block-styled element, therefore it will find the last one and not the first (or in-between ones for that matter).

Comment: there *should* only be one, so i am not worried about that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the reason your code doesn't work is the use of `.length()` in the `for` loop condition. jQuery objects don't have a `.length()` method, they have a `.length` property. Drop the brackets and your code should work.

**EDIT:** For your requirement to display the divs one at a time you can do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var $divs = $("div.content_div").hide(),  // first hide all the divs
       i = 0;    
   $divs.eq(i).show();                       // then show the first

   $(".slide_button a").click(function() {        
       $divs.eq(i).hide();                   // on click hide the current div
       i = (i+1) % $divs.length;             // then update the index to
       $divs.eq(i).show();                   // show the next one
   });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7CcMh/

(The rest of my original answer:) 
The syntax you are using to access the individual elements is OK: if `$all_divs` is a jQuery object, which it is, then `$all_divs[0]` is a reference to the first DOM element in the jQuery object. However, jQuery provides the `.each()` method to make this process easier:

```
$('.content_div').each(function() {
     // here 'this' is the current DOM element, so:
     if (this.style.display == "block")
         this.style.display = "none";
     // OR, to access the current element through jQuery methods:
     $(this).css("display", "none");
});
```

Having said that, it seems you expect all but one element to be hidden already and you are finding that one and hiding it too. If so, you can achieve that in one line:

```
 $('.content_div').hide();
 // OR
 $('.content_div').css("display", "none");
```

jQuery methods like `.hide()` and `.css()` apply to all elements in the jQuery object they're called on.

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) method which lets you iterate through the selected elements.

```
$('.content_div').each(functon(index){
    if ($(this).is(':visible')) { 
        $(this).hide()
    } 
})
```

If you want to select the visible divs you can use the `:visible` selector:

> Selects all elements that are visible.

```
$('.content_div:visible').css('display', 'none'): // or $('.content_div:visible').hide()
```

**update:**

you can add a class to the anchor and try the following:

```
<center><a href='#' class="toggle">></a></center>
```

```
$('.toggle').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault()  
  if ($('.content_div:visible').next('.content_div').length != 0) {    
     $('.content_div:visible').hide().next('.content_div:hidden:first').show()
  } else {
       $('.content_div').hide().eq(0).show()
  }    
})
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sb2xg/2/)

Comment: this makes sense, the only issue is that after i change the one display to none, i want to change the next one to block, so that is why i figured i need an index. Basically i have 4 divs, and when i click a button i want the one that is visible to go away, and the next one in the list to appear.

Comment: @TroyCosentino you can use `next()` which selects the next element, try the updated answer.

Comment: Note that `.next()` selects the next element in the DOM, not necessarily the next one with the appropriate class.

Comment: @nnnnnn are you sure? i have used this method with class selectors. `.next( [selector] )`

Comment: Sorry, what I should've said is it selects the next _sibling_, optionally filtered by a selector - and if the next sibling doesn't match the selector nothing is returned (it doesn't skip ahead to later elements). But that would be fine for the OP since his divs are siblings. (But it wouldn't work if the ".content_div" elements were not siblings.)

Comment: so i would just need:
function toggle() {
 $('.content_div:visible').hide().siblings('.content_div:hidden:first').show()
}

Comment: thank you for all the help! im fairly new to jquery/javascript (obviously) and i had a lot of stupid mistakes that kept keeping it from working, i ended up moving to try a different response when i figured what i was doing wrong in them all. anyways, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the standard [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) method from JQuery.

```
$('.content_div').each(function(index) {
    // do work with the given index
    if (this.style.display == "block") {
        this.style.display = "none";
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Last changes:

http://jsfiddle.net/6fPLp/13/

Comment: still does not seem to be working.. does it adjust index automatically?

Comment: Can you please show your full source code? Or at list upload the related section to http://jsfiddle.net/? And yes, index is incremented each iteration.

Comment: Let me know if this is what you aim for